# Converting Hex bytes into coordinates

Tags: hex, decimal, coordinates

I'm trying to convert a Hex stream into Lat/Long coordinates.
The input stream is coming from a Meitrack tracker (P99G model), over TCP.
The input is in little-endian, in millionth of a degree
The specs can be found here: http://www.meitrack.com/cd-download/Protocols/MEITRACK_P99G_GPRS_Protocol.pdf - but it wasn't very useful.

Here's an example and what I'm expecting it to translate to:

Lat:
Input: efbfbdefbfbd5102
Expected output: 38.907163

Long: 52efbfbd68efbfbd
Expected output: -77.007786

(The expected output is coming from coordinates received over SMS at the same time)

I was able to decrypt other parameters by reversing the order of the bytes and translating to decimal, but it doesn't seem to apply to the coordinates.

Any help with figuring out how to convert the Hex bytes to decimal coordinates will be very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a P99G message parser a few years before, which I checked now to test the given lat/lon pair. It seems that the test input and the expected output don't match: according to the given encoding (and the working parser) the lat hex string translates to -272.777233, lon to -1111.49483.

When implementing the protocol the tricky part was how to properly locate the data packets in the input byte array, when messages contain different types and numbers of commands. So my guess is that not the encoding is problematic here, but the boundaries of the lat/lon pair are shifted, missed - identification of the message parts should be checked first to find the correct lat/lon byte sequences.